# Is there really no way to get the response body from a failed js fetch request?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The new js fetch [API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-global-fetch) fails the promise if the request fails (400):

```
fetch(uri).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Is there really no way to get the response body when this happens? e.g. to check an error code.

EDIT: I've created a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4x4xLwqo/ that calls this mockbin endpoint: http://mockbin.org/bin/d87acbb0-526e-4d66-aea4-b827d9c35031/view

EDIT 2: updated jsfiddle to use a better endpoint: https://jsfiddle.net/4x4xLwqo/2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fetch` won't go into `catch` if it encounters a HTTP error. You can handle that with a regular `then`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> A `fetch()` promise will reject with a `TypeError` when a network error is encountered, although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example. An accurate check for a successful `fetch()` would include checking that the promise resolved, then checking that the `Response.ok` property has a value of true.

And an accompanying example, from MDN as well:

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
      myImage.src = objectURL;
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Network response was not ok.');
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
});
```

Comment: did you try it? I end up in the catch block from a 400

Comment: see the jsfiddle above

Comment: @grahamrhay You're requesting insecure content (`"http://mockbin"`) from a secure (`"https://jsfiddle"`) page.

You can't do that.
Fetch is erroring out before ever asking the server.

Likewise, I'm not seeing access-control headers in mockbin responses.
If there's no access, again, that's not a server-error, that's a connection error.  If you had two TLS (or two 100% insecure) (sub)domains, and each one properly served access-control headers (or there was only a one-way data-transfer and the data-server had the access-headers), this should work just fine.

Comment: thank you. I've updated the jsfiddle to use a better example, and it works as expected. now I need to work out what's different with my service :(

Comment: turns out nginx doesn't like to add the CORS headers on a failed request